# Waves produced by a mass of water on the calm sea surface

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

Suppose we have a parallelepiped shaped box full of water on the surface of the sea. Suddenly the box disappears. What is the shape of the waves vs. time caused by the fall of the water contained in the box?

Comment: the problem is not well defined: the material of the box? If wood it would be floating.If metal it would sink immediately anyway. If made of a material with density equal to the water density it will be flat with the surface so no fall. How will the box disappear? slowly? delta(t)?

Comment: @Anna Oh come one now.

Comment: after initial spin up, wouldnt it just be a progressive wave? you could at first order use something like eta = A sin(k*x-omega*t) for 1-D traveling wave.

Comment: @annav: No matter about the material of the box. It's only a container for the water inside. The box is supposed to float with the bottom face coincident with the sea surface. The box desappear like $\delta(t)$. The situation described is only to understand the behaviour of a mass of water of volume $V$ and height $h$ posed on the surface of the sea.

Comment: In this unphysical situation, if delta(t) is larger than the velocity of waves on the surface, no waves will appear but a slow change in height propagating . If delta(t) is small there will be circular waves, cylindrical in this case for a parallelepiped, like the wave a stone thrown in the middle of the lake makes.

Comment: @annav: the problem is to model the 'unphysical' situation, that means to give a mathematical expression (if it's possible) of the waves generated

Comment: I am sure it is possible to simulate it with computers, but I doubt you will find somebody to do it for you. Waves are not a simple thing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boussinesq_approximation_%28water_waves%29